Weight painting blur tool issue
For some reason every time i use the blur tool for weight painting it messes up the center
At first I thought it was because of the mirror modifier, so i tried deleting and applying it, neither worked, and I am not sure what else it could be
I haven't had this problem before



The problem was that I accidentally filled in all the center vertices with a face.
